# Logic for “queryparam” assignment in JECGBOOT front-end components (using mixin)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

The responsive data in the Vue `<form>` should define the `queryParam` field in the data, such as

```
<template>
 <a-form >
      <a-form-item label="账号" :label-col="{ span: 5 }">
           <!--<a-input placeholder="请输入账号查询" v-model="queryParam.username"></a-input>-->
           
            <j-input ref="username" placeholder="输入账号模糊查询" **v-model="queryParam.username"**></j-input>
            </a-form-item>
</template>
<script>

export default{
  data(){
     return{
      **   queryParam:{username:''}**
     }
  }
}
</script>
```

But in JEECGBOOT ,The value of the queryparams object was not defined after using **JeecgListMixin**

```
           
            <j-input ref="username" placeholder="输入账号模糊查询" v-model="queryParam.username"></j-input>
           

export default{
  data(){
     return{
         
     }
  }
}
</script>
```

## 在mixin中定义queryParams

```
 data(){
    return {
      /* 查询条件-请不要在queryParam中声明非字符串值的属性 */
      **queryParam: {},**
}
```

## Why not report the error 'username is not defined' and how Mixin processes data？

I want to know what data is processed in Mixin or how to achieve bidirectional binding

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.